# Convert varchar to int, if error then return original value?

Tags: sql-server, exception, casting

For example, I have 2 tables like:

Table1:

```
Column1
0001
0002
000a
```

Table2:

```
Column2
0001
0002
000a
```

Both Column1 and Column2 have data type is varchar(10).
I have to join 2 table together, so my query should be

```
Select * from Table1 join Table2 on Table1.Column1 = Table2.Column2
```

But, as we know that join 2 table in varchar type is much slower than join 2 table in numeric type (my tables have millions rows). I think about try

```
Select * from Table1 join Table2 on Cast(Table1.Column1 as int) = 
Cast(Table2.Column2 as int)
```

Normally, it work fine and much faster. But If I got exception as in row 3 (000a), my query will be broke. So, I want to find a query like:

```
Select * from Table1 join Table2 on
try
    Cast(Table1.Column1 as int) = Cast(Table2.Column2 as int)
catch if exception then
    Table1.Column1 = Table2.Column2
```

Update:------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I have an ideal:

Firstly, use try_cast to select any row that is numeric data:

```
select * from Table1 t1
join Table2 t2 
on try_cast(t1.Column1 as bigint) =try_cast(t2.Column2 as bigint)
```

After that, select any row that if try_cast will become null (exception row):

```
select * from 
(select * from Table1 t1 where try_cast(t1.Column1 as bigint) is NULL and 
t1.Column1 is not NULL) as table1
join
(select * from Table2 t2 where try_cast(t2.Column2 as bigint) is NULL and 
t2.Column2 is not NULL) as table2
on table1.Column1=table2.Column2
```

And finally union all 2 result together and I will get what I want. I take a test and it is pretty fast. Are there anything wrong with my ideal or something I forgot then please let me know!

Comment: There's no way to really do this - anything that looks "kind of" like what you're asking for would have to inspect the contents of each string several times - far more than the current textual comparison will. The only semi-workable solution is to have an indexed, persisted computed column in each table that contains the numeric values, but even then, if you have to also fall back to textual comparison, I don't think it will come out ahead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join using integers, under some coditions there is fast approach, but you must know your data: convert your values to numbers. The idea of getting the numbers works like this:

```
SELECT Column1,
   ASCII(SUBSTRING(c1, 1, 1)) * 256 * 256 * 256
 + ASCII(SUBSTRING(c1, 2, 1)) * 256 * 256
 + ASCII(SUBSTRING(c1, 3, 1)) * 256 
 + ASCII(SUBSTRING(c1, 4, 1)) AS Column1Num
FROM Table1
```

result:

```
Column1    Column1Num
---------- -----------
0001       808464433
0002       808464434
000a       808464481
```

This sticks with your example of having all values 4 characters long. The key is to find expression which creates *unique* number for every unique value and which is still applicable to all your records. Then use this expression as key for your `JOIN`.

- if not all values are of same length, you can compensate it (e.g. by `SPACE()` function)
- if your digits are actually hexadecimal (0123456789abcdef) you can decrease the quotient from `256` to `16` after you convert every digit to value 0..15 before applying the quotient
- *this is just to show you alternative approach* - knowing your data can show you optimum calculation formula but also can show that no such calculation is possible

*Main tip:* evaluate performance of all approaches (*[1]* joining varchars, *[2]* approach from your question update, *[3]* approach suggested in this answer) and pick the fastest